# Developer Branch Creation in AWS CodeCommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

As per mentioned title, I have some developer for eg. A, B, C & D. so here all developer commit the individual code on his/her branch, suppose A developer commit the code into the A branch in CodeCommmit Repository but I want A developer can't commit and can't delete B, C & D developer branch.

request you to all please help me for mentioned query how to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

I have refer AWS CodeCommit White paper but not getting solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want A developer can't commit and can't delete B, C & D developer branch." -- are you saying that you want to prevent them from committing, or are you saying that they should be able to commit but they are currently unable to commit due to some problem? More details, please.

Comment: A developer have A branch similarly B developer have B branch so i want A developer only commit the changes in A branch and can't commit and can't delete B developer B Branch.